# Multiple visits of cities in TSP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, traveling-salesman

Which subtour-elimination-constraint in TSP (travelling salesman problem) will allow multiple visits of each city on the route?
In my version of TSP, each city (except the departing warehouse) is allowed to be visited multiple times but the subtour elimination constraint does not allow it. When I remove this constraint, the answers (in some cases) are not valid (appearance of subtours).
My current subtour elimination constraint is

```
Ui+Uj-k*Xij <= k-1
```

Comment: This can be handled in preprocessing. Replace the cost coefficient `c(i,j)` by the length of the shortest path from i to j.  Now apply your TSP algorithm.